# Applying CSS properties to an image with variables in JS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to add css properties to an image that is set to a variable:

```
<script>
var img = '<img src="../common/img/check-mark.png">';
var imgCheck = img.css({'border':'1px solid red'});
$(function(){
    $('.content li').before(imgCheck);
});
</script>
```

The image shows up without the css properties:

```
<script>
var img = '<img src="../common/img/check-mark.png">';
$(function(){
    $('.content li').before(img);
});
</script>
```

If I add the css properties after the .before, it applies the css to the whole li.

```
<script>
var img = '<img src="../common/img/check-mark.png">';
$(function(){
    $('.content li').before(img).css({'border':'1px solid red'});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you create a string of HTML, not a jQuery object containing an `<img>` element:

```
var img = '<img src="../common/img/check-mark.png">';
```

And then try to use the CSS method on that string, which can't work, as strings don't have a `css()` method; instead you'd first need to create a jQuery object (using that string of HTML):

```
$(img).css({'border' : '1px solid red'});
```

```js
var img = '<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/250/250/" />';

$(img).css({'border' : '1px solid red'}).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

References:

- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 1):

`.before()` returns the element(s) being operated on, not the element you inserted.

Reverse the operation like this:

```
$(img).insertBefore('.content li').css({'border':'1px solid red'});
```

or create it like this:

```
$("<img>", {
    src: "../common/img/check-mark.png",
    css: {border:'1px solid red'},
    insertBefore: ".content li"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an `<img>` in a variable; you have the HTML code for an image. You can do what you're trying to do like this:

```
var img = $("<img/>", {
  src: "../common/img/check-mark.png",
  css: { border: "1px solid red" }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.content li').before(img).css({'border':'1px solid red'});
```

Here you are adding the CSS to `$('.content li')`

Add it to the img handle: `$(img).css({'border':'1px solid red'});`